# A question about Euler's Totient: $\frac1 {\phi(n)} = \frac1 n \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

*Show that $\frac1 {\phi(n)} = \frac1 n \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}$ for all positive integers n*

In class we solved this question by  observing that both sides are multiplicative functions and they should be equal at prime values. There is this another method we have done that I cant understand. I have to express right-hand side(the summation) as a multiplication but I just cant figure out. It would be better if you could give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where $\mu(d)$ is?

Comment: If $f$ is multiplicative, can you write $$\prod_{p\mid n} \bigl( 1 - f(p)\bigr)$$ as a similar sum? What do you need to change to get $$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)^2 f(d)\,?$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ? Unfortunately I couldn't continue :(

Comment: I'll say $$\prod_{p\mid n} \bigl(1 - f(p)\bigr) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)f(d)$$ for multiplicative $f$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the idea you mention. The simplest thing that comes to my mind to prove that identity is to use the fact that if $f$ is multiplicative then $\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$ is multiplicative as well; then you can easily finish by using the fact that $\mu$ only acts on square-free integers.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $ \frac{n}{\phi(n)} = \sum\limits_{d \mid n} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182720) and [How do I show that $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}=\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\varphi(d)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53919)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we write this as

$$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = \prod_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\varphi(d)}.$$

The LHS is by definition

$$\prod_{p|n} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}} = \prod_{p|n} \frac{p}{p-1}$$

where the product is over prime divisors of $n.$ Now since $\mu(n)$ and $\varphi(n)$ are multiplicative and the product on the RHS only includes terms $d$ that are products of primes we get for the RHS

$$\prod_{p|n} \left(1+\frac{\mu(p)^2}{\varphi(p)}\right)
= \prod_{p|n} \left(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)
= \prod_{p|n} \frac{p}{p-1}$$

the same as the LHS and we are done.